# Jupyter notebook fails to start

Tags: jupyter-notebook

While trying to open jupyter notebook through terminal on macos, it shows:

"from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/markupsafe/**init**.py)"

So I tried to open through anaconda navigator but it fails to open stating:
/Users/hiraltalati/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
(base) hiraltalati@Hirals-MacBook-Air ~ % /Users/hiraltalati/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
INTEL MKL ERROR: dlopen(/Users/hiraltalati/opt/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_core.1.dylib, 9): image not found.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.1.dylib.
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting advice [on the Jupyter Discourse site here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-is-not-opening/15148) and at links therein, such as https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-notebook-launch-error/15144 .

Comment: @Wayne Yes, I tried uninstalling markupsafe, reinstalling and even upgrading, downgrading its version but nothing works.

Comment: @Wayne 'python3 -m pip install markupsafe==2.0.1' and then tried opening jupyter notebook. It worked!     Thankyou!